# File operation not permitted in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, file, uri

I have silverlight application in asp.net web. In web application i have folder which contains XPS file. Now In silverlight on button click event I am opening a popup box which contains XPS Viewer.

On button click event i'am sending URI to public function of Popup control.

and i am trying to create filestream from that uri path but getting error

File operation not permitted Access to path "" denied ?
Using AbsolutePath m trying to creat file stream

From which property of URI object i should try to create FileStream or how do i achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a filestream from there will not be permissible as silverlight is in a sandboxed environment. If you need a stream open the the file first with webclient and OpenReadAsync and then use the stream from the result.

Have a look at the answer [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/11911.aspx) to see more or less how to do it.

You might also be interested in [this](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Loading-Files-From-a-Remote-Server-in-Silverlight.aspx) link.

Comment: First link is dead. Please quote relevant portions of solutions rather than just link dumping. SO is meant to be a content provider, not a content aggregator.

Comment: I did give a description of how to do it, see first sentence? Unfortunately I don't have a reference to the original link anymore